# URL to get the video file or stream from YouTube?

Tags: youtube

This url returns a huge html page which is for watching the video.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=some_id
```

I can't go through all the HTML tags and get the right url to the actual video. I believe there is a url from where the actual video stream is coming. I expect it to be something like,

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_the_video?id=some_id
Or,
http://www.youtube.com/get_the_video/some_id.mp4
```

I can't find any information about the correct url for the video.

Is this how YouTube maintain it's video link or their is something else?

Do they always change the url?

I want to do something like this in HTML to play the video.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
        <source src="http://www.youtube.com/get_the_video?id=some_id" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

*(I am new to how YouTube works. Need some guidance)*

Comment: Here's an updated answer for June, 2016 http://stackoverflow.com/a/37779863/68788

Answer (score 18):

You can use [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/)
to download or get the stream url from YouTube.

to download a video,

```
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=some_id
```

or

```
youtube-dl some_id
```

to get the stream url, do

```
youtube-dl -g http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=some_id
```

Basically the url is parsed from the html source code of the original page.

Comment: the recommendation is awesome. However, the `-g` flag doesn't work for me. Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: It's working for me. Try installing the latest version from  [here](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html)

Checkout the [documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#verbosity--simulation-options) too.

Regards

Comment: @Junaid stream url would keep on changing I guess for security reasons ?

Comment: still cant get at youtube video file link. even though they dont own the content?

Comment: Works flawlessly even in 2022.  to the wonderful team that keeps `youtube-dl` up to date!