# How to get link MP4, FLV from Youtube

Tags: php, youtube

**I am new to PHP so plz bear with me.** I have to extract `mp4, flv or other` formats from youtube link.

**Running Example :** Go to [this site](http://en.savefrom.net/) and enter any [**Youtube url like this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BP38770KNo).

and hit enter. It retrieves the .mp4 or flv link. I want to achieve the same but don't know where to start. and when i inspect youtube by pressing Ctrl+shift+I. I can't find anything. How can i get a mp4 or flv link using youtube url.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402457/how-to-get-direct-url-for-youtube-videos